# How to remove dynamic digits of prefix

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the format of the values in the Array(OutArray) mentioned in the below code. The Array will return as six digit numbers, with preceding 0's and with signs(+ or -) to make up the numbers. If the actual values are 5678, -5000, 8, the Array will return as +005678, -005000, +000008. I couldn't change this datatype format since its the only way the instrument will return data.

I'm trying to remove the Prefix 0 and also the '+' that comes along with each value. But the class is that, I don't know how many 0's will be there as Prefix since the values returned are dynamic. I'm struck in this line of code,

```
                InArray = MID(Step, "", "")
```

Where I actually wanted to identify the first non-zero value. Is there any way to do this?

```
 Public Function copy_XY()

   Dim idn As String
   idn = instrument.ReadString()  ' Reading a value from instrument (Dynamic)    
   Dim OutArray() As String
   OutArray = Split(idn)
   Dim Step As Variant
   Dim InArray As String
   For Each Step in OutArray
      InArray = MID(Step, "", "")
   Next Step

End function
```

When I use CInt as below I'm getting overflow error.

```
   Dim Val() As Int
   Val(0) = CInt(OutArray(0))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all you need is `CInt`.

Comment: I'm getting Overflow error when I use CInt.

Comment: In VBA, the maximum value of an **Integer** is 32,767 - which is only 5 digits in length. So, understandably you would receive an overflow error when using `CInt()`. You should be using `CLng()` instead.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs If I use CLng, will it return 0 if the value is 000000?

Comment: Yes it will. And you need to declare your array variable `Val()` as type **Long** as well. But according to your edit - you declared it as type `Int` (`Dim Val() As Int`), which is either a typo or you're not using VBA.

Comment: Yes it's a typo. When I try with CLng and declared my array variable as Long. It throws subscript out of range error

Comment: Subscript out of range has nothing to do with `CLng()`. It has something to do with the bounds of your array. Your array was probably never initialized. Static arrays are declared with the dimension: `Dim Val(10) As Long`. Dynamic arrays can be dimensionalized after its declaration: `Dim Val() As Long: ReDim Val(10)` or by assigning an array `Val = Split(...)`, `Val = Array(...)`, `Val = Arr2`

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Sorry I forgot to tell, the values from the Outer Array (OutArray) will have signs (+ or -).  That's why CLng is not working I suppose. So the expected output is if it's + sign I want it to remove. If it's a - sign I want to use it. Something like If the OutArray value returns as +005677 I want to change it to 5677, where as if it returns as -000056, I want to change it to -56.

Comment: `Dim Var As Long: Var = CLng("+001234")` works for me, so you have other issues with your code.

Comment: Converting is process heavy. Always try and declare your variables what you intend to use them for..Declaring a `string` and adding a "number" but later wanting to convert to `long` is bad coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears from the comments that there are some strange issues that we are not being told of from your code. So let's just drop the simple `CLng()` conversion methods and use some Regular Expressions.

I assume from your usage of `Split()`, you return a string that contains a +/- and six numeric characters delimited by spaces *(since you are using the default delimiter of Split - which is a space)*. That would make your data look something like:

```
"+650280 +001503 +000000 -001258 +001250 -009870 +798023"
```

Using Regular Expressions (RegExp for short), you can easily match these numbers using a very simple pattern and place them into a collection. From there, it's easy to move the collection into an array that has been declared as type Long. Since you are converting these values to a Long data type, you no longer have to worry about your non-significant 0's.

```
Public Function copy_XY()

    Dim ValArr() As Long, i As Long
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

        .Pattern = "[+-]\d+"
        .Global = True

        With .Execute(instrument.ReadString)

            ' Place the collection into an array
            ReDim ValArr(.Count - 1)
            For i = 0 To .Count - 1
                ValArr(i) = .Item(i)
            Next

        End With

    End With

    ' Print the values to the immediate window to show it works
    For i = 0 To UBound(ValArr)
        Debug.Print ValArr(i)
    Next

End Function
```

---

### Breaking Down the Pattern

So, we provided RegExp with the following pattern `[+-]\d+`. First, it's important to mention that we changed the **Global Flag** to `True`, because this will match every instance of this pattern in your string. Keeping it at false would have only matched the first case of your pattern and stop.

Now onto the pattern itself:

- `[+-]` is a character class (`[...]`) that will match any character within it - so in this case either a `+` or a `-`
- `\d` is a special token that means *any single digit*

  - We modified this "any *single* digit" with a quantifier `+`, that means *one or more of*. So `\d+` means *one or more of \d*.
  - We could have been much more specific and used `\d{6}`, which would have required exactly 6 of `\d`. Something to keep in mind.